# angular 2 select option with object value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript

im getting the list of object value from API and inside the object there has a property for identify the selected item 
i am able to bind the items list to view

here is the json data

[image]

here is the my code :

```
   <select class="form-control"  name="Underwriter">
 <option *ngFor="let underwriter of policyModel?.underwriterList" [ngValue]="underwriter.value" >{{underwriter.text}}</option>
  </select>
```

any way to make the selected item  ?

Comment: Well what's the question??

Comment: any way to make the selected item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add just a `[selected]` to your select and check which `underwriter` has property `selected` as `true`.

like so:

```
 <select class="form-control" (change)="onChangeunderwriter($event)" name="Underwriter">
     <option *ngFor="let underwriter of policyModel?.underwriterList" [ngValue]="underwriter.value" [selected]="underwriter.selected == true">{{underwriter.text}}</option>
 </select>
```

So just add:

```
[selected]="underwriter.selected == true"
```

A simplified [**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/sS5RY6adosKvrfLXgG72?p=preview)

Comment: this was work but i had add the formControlName="uw" to <select>   now selected item is not working why is that ?

Comment: If you are using form, you need to set the `uw` with the preselected value instead.

Comment: can u plz tell me difference between [(ngModel)]  and [ngModel]

Comment: basically `[ngModel]` is oneway binding and `[(ngModel)]` is two way binding :)

Answer (score 0):

In your question you say you want to "make" the selected item, which I assume means set it.  This is how I have done it, but there might be other better ways.

You need to set the `[attr.selected]` in the option tag

```
 <select class="form-control"  name="Underwriter">
 <option *ngFor="let underwriter of policyModel?.underwriterList" [ngValue]="underwriter.value"  [attr.selected]="underwriter.text === underwriterTextString ? true: null">{{underwriter.text}}</option>
  </select>
```

Then it your code you need to set `underwriterTextString` when the WebService API returns a result.

If `underwriter.text` does not work then try `underwriter.value`

However, in your comment below you now say that you want to "get" the selected item.  This can be done by using the change event in the `select` tag

```
 <select class="form-control" (change)="onChangeunderwriter($event)" name="Underwriter">
     <option *ngFor="let underwriter of policyModel?.underwriterList" [ngValue]="underwriter.value"  [attr.selected]="underwriter.text === underwriterTextString ? true: null">{{underwriter.text}}</option>
      </select>
```

Then in your code your need something like this;

```
onChangeunderwriter(event) {

//the value will be set in event.target.value;


  }
```

Comment: i need to get the selected item from object list inside the object you can see there has a property call 'selected '